# How to get error logs in NPM ng2-file-upload in Angular 5?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, error-logging, ng2-file-upload

I am using npm `ng2-file-upload` package to upload an image file to S3.

I am using `onErrorItem` hook to know if any error, and I am getting `item.isError` as `true`,

```js
this.uploader.onErrorItem = ((item, response, status, headers): any => { // response=""; status=0; headers={};
          console.log(item.isError);      // true
        });
```

which means, file upload is failed. I also checked S3 and there was no file. But, **there are no error logs about failure** in the `item` object.

By the way, I am uploading a file with a pre-signed-url. This is [Github reference](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/925#issuecomment-435873557)

So, can anyone please tell me, how can I see error logs in `ng2-file-upload` after failing to upload a file in S3?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the error using **Network Tab** in **Developer Tools in Google Chrome**.

But it would have been much quicker if `ng2-file-upload` had any error logging mechanism.

This is how we can simply check any error coming while you send an API request.

[image: Hover on status]